# Query perfoming full table scan

Tags: mysql, performance

My query is not using any indexes. Query performing full table scan. What can I do to avoid this?

```
explain select * from 
timed_delivery_messages 
where start_time <= '06:39' 
and end_time > '06:39' 
and mode='Active' 
and rotation_weight like '%,45,%' 
and substr(day_of_week, 2, 1) = 'T' 
limit 1;
```

Explain Plan

```
+----+-------------+-------------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table                   | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | timed_delivery_messages | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |   22 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Tables:

```
mysql> show create table timed_delivery_messages\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: timed_delivery_messages
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `timed_delivery_messages` (
  `row_create` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `row_mod` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `rule_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `start_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `day_of_week` varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rotation_weight` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mode` varchar(10) DEFAULT 'active',
  `long_message` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `short_message` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`rule_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: I bet it's `rotation_weight like '%,45,%'` and `substr(day_of_week, 2, 1) = 'T'` that are responsible for full table scan.

Comment: Plus I don't see indexes on `start_time`, `end_time` and `mode`

Comment: Thanks @@aleks i was created indexes on start_time, end_time and mode .Now it was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You must create one group index with columns
`start_time`, 
`end_time`,
`mode`

And also do experiment to include `day_of_week` into this index. Maybe it will speed up your system